# Clojure filter composition with reduce

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, function-composition

I have a higher order predicate

```
(defn not-factor-of-x? [x]
  (fn [n]
    (cond 
      (= n x) true
      (zero? (rem n x)) false
      :else true)))
```

which returns a predicate that checks if the given argument n is not a factor of x. 
Now I want to filter a list of numbers and find which are not factors of say '(2 3). One way to do this would be :

```
(filter (not-factor-of-x? 3) (filter (not-factor-of-x? 2) (range 2 100)))
```

But one can only type so much. In order to do this dynamically I tried function composition :

```
(comp (partial filter (not-factor-of-x? 2)) (partial filter (not-factor-of-x? 3)))
```

And it works. So I tried reducing the filters, like this:

```
(defn compose-filters [fn1 fn2]
  (comp (partial filter fn1) (partial filter fn2)))
(def composed-filter (reduce compose-filters (map not-factor-of-x? '(2 3 5 7 11))))
(composed-filter (range 2 122))   ; returns (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .......)
```

So, why the filter composition is not working as intended ?

Comment: what about (remove (factor-of-x? ...) ...) instead of (filter (NOT-factor-of-x? ...) ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your problem with `(reduce compose-filters ...` let's look a bit at what that actually does. First, it uses `filter` on the first two predicates and composes them.. The result of that is a new function from sequences to sequences. The next iteration then calls `filter` on that function, when filter expects a predicate. Every sequence is a truthy value, so that new filter will now never remove any values because it's using a "predicate" which always returns truthy values. So in the end, only the very last filter actually does any filtering - in my REPL your code removes the numbers 22, 33, 44 and so on because 11 is a factor in them. I think the reduce you want to do here is more like

```
(reduce comp (map (comp (partial partial filter) not-factor-of-x?) '(2 3 5 7 11)))
```

Note how because we only want to call `(partial filter)` once per number, you can move that into the mapping step of the mapreduce. As to how I'd do this, considering that you produce all your predicates together:

```
(map not-factor-of-x? '(2 3 5 7 11))
```

it seems more natural to me  to just combine the predicates at that point using [`every-pred`](http://conj.io/store/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clojure.core/every-pred/)

```
(apply every-pred (map not-factor-of-x? '(2 3 5 7 11)))
```

and use one `filter` on that predicate. It seems to communicate the intent a little more clearly ("I want values satisfying every one of these preds") and unlike composition of `(partial filter ...)` it avoids making an intermediate sequence for each predicate.
(In Clojure 1.7+ you can also avoid this by composing the transducer version of `filter`).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to compose functions and/or improve your code. Here's one:

```
(defn factor? [n x]
  (and (not= n x) (zero? (rem n x))))

(->> (range 2 100)
     (remove #(factor? % 2))
     (remove #(factor? % 3)))

;; the same as the above
(->> (range 2 100)
     (remove (fn [n] (some #(factor? n %) [2 3]))))
```